# Static variable for state management

Tags: android, kotlin, static, state

I'm having trouble understanding the problem in this scenario.

I have a class used for Analytics Tracking, lets call it `FlurryTracker`, 
it has 2 methods `StartTrackingScreen(ScreenName)` and `StopTrackingScreen()`.

Now if I have a static var called `screenName` and each time start tracking screen is called `screenName` is reassigned.

```
startTrackingScreen(activity: Activity, screen: DhTracker.Screen<T>) {
        screenName = screen.getName()
        val lastScreen = Singleton.getLastScreen()
        //If last screen is not same as current screen

            FlurryAgent.logEvent(screenName, true)

    }
}


override fun stopTrackingScreen() {
    //New screen will start tracking before lastScreen tracking is stopped.
    if (enabled) {
        FlurryAgent.endTimedEvent(Singleton.getLastScreen()?.getName())
    }
}

companion object{
  lateinit var screenName : String
}
```

These methods are called in `onStart()` and `onStop()` in the app itself.

So with that being said, we are only tracking 1 screen at a time because when the user transitions to a new screen, `onStop()` and `onStart()` will be called.

So even though screenName is static, every time the lifecycle methods are called, that static var is being reassigned. Since a phone can't have 2 activites running at the same time, there will only be 1 instance of my tracker active at a time.

I don't really see the problem with using a static here, although I know best practices say that `screenName` should be created with every new instance. Am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: What is your question? Also, why do you need it to be in a `companion object`? (It *is not static* in fact)

Comment: What is the problem using a static var for state management?

Comment: It is not static, It will only be static if you use `@JvmStatic` on it. The problem is that anyone can tamper with that and it adds no benefit.

Comment: I thought that `companion object` acted in the same way as static, in that the var `screenName` is now shared across all instances of my Tracking class

Comment: I see what your saying though, while it is possible to do something like this with a static var. There are no benefits and it only adds complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that.

The two main patterns for something like this are static variables & methods or a singleton (That is often static so you can use it from different paths without passing it around).  Both of these approaches are functionally identical.

The negatives for the static class are:

- Difficult to test due to the fact that you have to replace the static method
- Difficult to create a second instance
- Difficult to pass around if you decide you want to (Some people like to know what classes are used by a given path for testing purposes)

These aren't that bad, you can live with them--however none of these issues exist if you use a singleton.  You can easily pass it around, change it's behavior, convert it to use injection instead of the singleton pattern, …

So I can't really come up with a reason to ever use the static approach, there aren't any advantages.